# using dynamic with reflection

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, reflection

I've heared that the best practice to create an instance using reflection is by using a dynamic type variable.
What it means is that when we use the `Activator.CreateInstance()` method(that returns object) we assign it into a dynamic type instead of object type:

```
dynamic dog = Activator.CreateInstance("Zoo.Dog");
dog.Bark();
```

Instead of:

```
object dog = Activator.CreateInstance("Zoo.Dog");
Dog realDog = (Dog)dog;
realDog.Bark();
```

Is there any good reason to use dynamic other than the lack of casting?

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: `dynamic` is intended for interoperability with scripting languages, or for use with other kinds of objects that do not have a common static type. (The ASP.NET MVC `ViewBag`, `ExpandoObject` in general and such.) Also, "lack of casting" doesn't really exactly describe how it works - dynamic method calls / expressions are processed fairly differently than static ones are.

Comment: I know what dynamic is. My question is why the example I shown above is considered to be best practice when creating instance using reflection

Comment: **is** it really best practice? I mean it is somewhat the only elegant option if you should only know the class to instantiate at runtime (because then you **cannot** know the right type at compile time). If I know the type during design time I would always prefer static typing - there just is not a single disadvantage...

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the type you are creating your instance from, then there is no need to use a `dynamic` type. You might need to use a `dynamic` type if you do not have access (in a static way) to the type, for instance when loading dynamically an assembly. If you use a dynamic type instead of a known type, each type you call a member of your instance that will use reflection under the hood. Besides, you won't have intellisense using `dynamic` types.

You can use the generic method `CreateInstance<T>` from the `Activator` class to create your instance.

```
Dog dog = Activator.CreateInstance<Dog>();
dog.Bark();
```

The `dynamic` keyword makes easier the interaction with dynamic languages (IronPython, IronRuby for instance) ([Dynamic Language Runtime DLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx)) or COM Interop APIs, but it is not recommended (nor needed) to use it with known types.